Proving that a sequence converges, with the epsilon definition
I want to prove that the following sequence $x_n = \frac{3+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}}$ converges and has a limit.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{3+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}} \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\frac{3}{n}+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}}{\frac{2n}{n}-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}} \Rightarrow \lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{0+0}{2+0}=0$$
I want to show that for any $\epsilon$>0 there exists an N such that for all n > N, $|x_n-L|$ < $\epsilon$ where L = 0
Let $\epsilon$>0. I want to find N such that for all n>N, $|x_0-0 |$< $\epsilon$
$$|x_n-0| =|\frac{3+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}}-0| = \frac{3+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon$$
I now choose N≥max($\frac{6}{\epsilon},\frac{4}{\epsilon^2}$), so for all n>1, then if:
$$n≥N \Rightarrow \frac{3+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}} <\frac{3+\sqrt{n}}{n}= \frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}< \frac{3}{\frac{6}{\epsilon}} +\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{4}{\epsilon^2}}}=\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2} = \epsilon $$
Is this the correct way to do it? I know I made a mistake,  because my TA told me that it seemed like a rough draft, but unfortunately didn't have enough time to explain it further.

I think it is true and no leap of logic, except two parts. One is lack of explain, and another is wrong. 1st is $\frac{3+\sqrt n}{2n-\sqrt n}<\frac{3+\sqrt n}{n}$. You had to explain that $n>1$ so that inequality holds. 2nd is $\frac{3+\sqrt n}{n} < \frac 3{n}+\frac 1{\sqrt n}$. It is not $<$, but $=$.

And one more(but not very important). You have to explain that there exists positive integer $N$ greater than $\max(\frac6\epsilon,\frac4{\epsilon^2)$. The easiest way is using archemedian property.

I hate such exercises! Definitions of modern mathematics are not made to deal with examples but to prove theorems which can easily be applied to examples. The beginning of your post (using theorems about convergent sequences) demonstrates the power of this very general strategy. Asking for an explicit $N(\varepsilon)$ spoils it all.

M.H Lee, can this simply be done by choosing N= $⌈ max(\frac{6}{\epsilon},\frac{4}{\epsilon^2})⌉$ ie. the ceiling function?

" You have to explain that there exists positive integer N greater than"  .... If the OPs class has already shown that the natural numbers are not bounded above then the OP doesn't have to explain that.  "can this simply be done by choosing N= ⌈max(6ϵ,4ϵ2)⌉ ie. the ceiling function?"  Well, no because the only way we know the ceiling function exists is because we have previous shown the naturals are unbounded.

"I now choose N≥max(6ϵ,4ϵ2), so for all n>1"  Might be easier to say.  $n > \max (\frac 6\epsilon, \frac 4{\epsilon^2}, 1)$.  But to be thourough you may have to show that $n >\max(1\frac 4{\espilon^2})\implies \sqrt n > \frac 2\epsilon$.

This is fine, Just explain the inequalities.

Use $2n-\sqrt n\geq\sqrt n$, and when $n\geq9$, $3\leq\sqrt n$.
So we have
$$\left|\frac{3+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}}-0\right|
\leq\frac{3+\sqrt{n}}{n}\leq\frac{2\sqrt n}{n}=\frac{2}{\sqrt n}<\epsilon,$$
taking $N>\max\{9,4/\epsilon^2\}$ will be OK.

I was writing down exactly this way too!

@user
"Great" minds think alike.

You don't need the best possible result.
Since $n \ge \sqrt{n}$
for $n \ge 1$,
and
$\sqrt{n} \ge 3$ for
$n \ge 9$,
$\begin{array}\\
 \frac{3+\sqrt{n}}{2n-\sqrt{n}}
&\le  \frac{2\sqrt{n}}{n}\\
&=  \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}}\\
&\lt \epsilon
\quad\text{for } n \ge \dfrac{4}{\epsilon^2}\\
\end{array}
$
so
$n \ge \max(9,\dfrac{4}{\epsilon^2})
$
will do.

$n > \dfrac{4}{\epsilon^2}$.

Thanks. Upvoted.

Let: $$ d_n = \frac{(3 + \sqrt n)}{(2n - \sqrt n )} = \frac{(3 + \sqrt n)}{(2n - \sqrt n) } * \frac{(2n + \sqrt n )}{ (2n + \sqrt n) } $$
$$ = \frac{7}{4n-1} + \frac {2 \sqrt n }{4n-1}  + \frac{3 \sqrt n}{n(4n-1)} $$
Let
$$a_n = \frac{7}{4n-1}$$
$$b_n = \frac{2 \sqrt n}{4n-1} $$
$$c_n = \frac{3 \sqrt n}{n(4n-1)} $$
Then:
$$ d_n = a_n + b_n + c_n $$
It must be proven that the limit of the sequence $ d_n $ is:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } d_{n} = 0  $$
First, we examine $a_n$. $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 $, let:
$$ N_1 \gt max(1,\frac{7}{3 \epsilon}) $$
Then
$ n \gt N_1 $ implies: $ n \gt \frac{7}{3 \epsilon} $ implies $ \frac{7}{3n} \lt \epsilon $.
A lower bound is placed on a factor of
$d_n$, namely $(4n-1)$. For $ n \gt 1 $ , make $ 4n - 1 \gt 3n. $ Thus,
$$ \frac{7}{4n-1} \lt \frac{7}{3n} \lt \epsilon $$
and $ n \gt N_1 $ implies:
$$ | a_n - 0 | \lt \epsilon $$
Using the definition of the limit of a sequence,
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n} = 0 $$
and $a_n$ converges to zero.
Second, we examine $ b_n $ $\forall \epsilon \gt 0$, let:
$$ N_2 \gt max(1,\frac{4}{9\epsilon^2}) $$
Then $n \gt N_2 $ implies $n \gt \frac{4}{9 \epsilon^2} $ implies $ \sqrt n \lt \frac{2}{3\epsilon}$ implies $\frac{2 \sqrt n}{3 n} \lt \epsilon$.
A lower bound is placed on a factor of $d_n$, namely $4n-1$. For $n \gt 1 $, $4n-1 \gt 3n$ which implies:
$$ \frac{2 \sqrt n}{4n-1} \lt \frac{2 \sqrt n}{3n} \lt \epsilon. $$ . Thus $n \gt N_2 $ implies:
$$ | b_n - 0 | \lt \epsilon $$
By the definition of the limit of a sequence,
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} b_{n} = 0 $$
and $b_n$ converges to zero.
Third, we examine $c_n$. $ \forall \epsilon \gt 0 $ let:
$$ N_3 \gt max(1 ,\frac{1}{\epsilon^{\frac{2}{3}}}) $$
Then $ n \gt N_3 $ implies: $ n \gt \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}} $ implies $ \epsilon \gt \frac{1}{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}.  $
A lower bound is placed on a factor of $d_n$, namely $(4n-1)$. For $ n \gt 1 $, make $ 4n-1 \gt 3n. $ This implies
$$ \frac{ 3 \sqrt n}{n(4n-1)} \lt \frac{ 3 \sqrt n}{ (n)(3n) } = \frac{1}{n^\frac{3}{2}} \lt \epsilon $$
Thus $n \gt N_3$ implies:
$$ | c_n - 0 | \lt \epsilon $$
By the definition of the limit of a sequence:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} c_{n} = 0 $$
and $ c_n $ converges to zero.
Putting everything together:
Using the definition of the limit of a sequence from $a_n$ , $b_n$ , and $c_n$,
Since,
$$ \lim_{ n \rightarrow \infty } a_{n} = 0 $$
There exists an $ N_1 $ such that: $ n \gt N_1 $  implies:
$$ |a_n - 0| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{3} $$
Since:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } b_n = 0 $$
there exists an $ N_2 $ such that $ n \gt N_2 $ implies:
$$ |b_n - 0| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{3} $$
Since:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} c_{n} = 0 $$
there exists $ N_3 $ such that $ n \gt N_3 $ implies:
$$ |c_n - 0| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{3} $$
Let $ N = max(N_1, N_2, N_3) $ such that $ n \gt N $ implies:
$$  |d_n - 0| = |a_n + b_n + c_n - (0 +0 +0) | \leq |a_n - 0| + |b_n - 0| + |c_n - 0| \lt \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{\epsilon}{3} = \epsilon 
$$
implies:
$$ |d_n - 0| \lt \epsilon $$
and:
$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} d_n = 0 $$
and $d_n$ converges to zero.

Actually, I prove a somewhat stronger result than that requested by the original poster.  In the posted question, the use of the word sequence at the start of the question indicates that it is sufficient to limit the assertion to $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+}.~$
I proved instead that the assertion holds for $~n \in \Bbb{R^+},~$ from which one can infer that the narrower assertion also holds.

Alternative Approach:
$\underline{\text{Preliminary Results}}$
PR-1
$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} 2n - \sqrt{n} = \infty.$ 
Proof
$~\forall ~n \in \Bbb{R_{> 1}}, ~n > \sqrt{n} \implies 2n - \sqrt{n} > n.$ 
So, given any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ choose $~M = \max(2,\epsilon).~$ 
Then, $~\displaystyle \forall n \geq M, ~2n - \sqrt{n} > n \geq M \geq \epsilon.$
PR-2
$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} 2\sqrt{n} - 1 = \infty.$ 
Proof
$~\forall ~n \in \Bbb{R_{> 1}}, ~\sqrt{n} > 1 \implies 2\sqrt{n} - 1 > \sqrt{n}.$ 
So, given any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ choose $~M = \max(2,\epsilon^2).~$ 
Then, $~\displaystyle \forall n \geq M,~$ 
$\displaystyle 2\sqrt{n} - 1 > \sqrt{n},~$ and
$~\displaystyle \sqrt{n} \geq \sqrt{M} \geq \epsilon.$

$x_n = y_n + z_n,~$ where:

$\displaystyle y_n = \frac{3}{2n - \sqrt{n}}.$

$\displaystyle z_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2n - \sqrt{n}} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n} - 1}.$


So, it is (presumably, depending on what theory the original poster has been exposed to) sufficient to prove that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = 0 ~~~\text{and} ~~~\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = 0.$$
At this point, it is unclear how long-winded the remainder of this answer should be.  I will err on the side of caution, and continue to construct $~\epsilon$-oriented analysis for the remainder of this problem.

$\underline{\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = 0}$
For any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ choose $~\displaystyle \epsilon_1 = \frac{3}{\epsilon}.$
By PR-1,
$$\exists M \in \Bbb{R^+} ~~~\text{such that} ~~~\forall n \geq M, ~2n - \sqrt{n} > \epsilon_1 \implies $$
$$0 < \frac{1}{2n - \sqrt{n}} < \frac{1}{\epsilon_1} = \frac{\epsilon}{3} \implies $$
$$0 < y_n = \frac{3}{2n - \sqrt{n}} < \epsilon.$$

$\underline{\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = 0}$
For any $~\epsilon > 0,~$ choose $~\displaystyle \epsilon_1 = \frac{1}{\epsilon}.$
By PR-2,
$$\exists M \in \Bbb{R^+} ~~~\text{such that} ~~~\forall n \geq M, ~2\sqrt{n} - 1 > \epsilon_1 \implies $$
$$0 < z_n = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n} - 1} < \frac{1}{\epsilon_1} = \epsilon. $$
